# Apache Camel - Servlet Component - is binding path variables possible?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a servlet and using a camel route to listen request from the servlet as below:

```
 from("servlet:///basepath?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
```

There is no problem with that, since matchOnUriPrefix is true, requests for the following url pattern are successfully listened by the route:

***host:port/basepath/dynamicSubPath***

What I want to have is that, is there any way that I can make the path variable (dynamicSubPath) to bind to an exchange property?

I know that I can get the path as below:

```
 String path = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, String.class);
```

But I dont want to do such string parsing. In spring mvc I can inject path variables to the controller as below:

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/basepath/{dynamicSubPath}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and then can get the dynamicSubPath variable as below:

```
 @PathVariable String dynamicSubPath
```

Is there a similar thing possible for  camel servlet component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that camel supports this.

By default all request headers and **query** parameters will be set as headers on the in message. The requested path is also present (as you pointed out via the header `Exchange.HTTP_PATH`) but not split up into its components.

I'm afraid you have to register a custom processor that parses the string and sets the path variables as message headers or exchange properties accordingly.

Comment: Yes this is not supported in plain HTTP with servlet. However if you use REST then you can use rest-dsl which support path bindings also with the servlet component. http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl

Comment: Thanks! At least now I know that it is not supported:)